# Updating and inserting new records into Teradata table from SAS

Tags: sas, teradata, proc-sql

I have a state table sitting in Teradata with 11 million rows and a unique row for every ID. I run logic in SAS that if a column (class) is updated, it updates the Teradata with the new record. Table structure in Teradata and the table generated in SAS is:

| id | class | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | date1 |
| 2 | Y | date2 |

If the class is updated in the SAS created table for an id, the class and updated_at columns are updated in Teradata (more columns can be updated as well). Moreover, if a new record (id) is added, it is inserted into Teradata.

I want to achieve this in SAS, without having to push the SAS table into Teradata, and use **merge into**. Every table created in SAS will be 11 million+ rows.

To update a record manually, I can just use this:

```
proc sql;
    update TD.TABLE_IN_TERADATA 
    set class = 'Z'
    where updated_at = date3;
quit;
```

Comment: Are you looking to just update the SAS table without updating the Teradata table? Do you want to do all of the updates in SAS and replace the Teradata table with the newly updated SAS table instead?

Comment: I want to update the Teradata table, using the SAS table. SAS creates a table of X million rows with unique IDs, a class and a date (run date). If the class (in the newly generated SAS table) of a particular ID changes from whatever is in Teradata, it updates that record and updated_at date in Teradata. If the ID generated by SAS does not exist in the Teradata table, it inserts a new record. I would like to only update the Teradata table in cases where the class changes (in SAS) if possible.

Comment: @StuSztukowski I was thinking of using this but not sure if it works to Teradata? `proc append base=TD.TERADATA_TABLE (multiload=yes upsert=yes)  data=WORK.SAS_TABLE;
run;`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you have a teradata master table with all your data. Then you have new SAS tables with data to update your master data.
To generate some sample data (only SAS tables, I don' have teradata at hand...):

```
data test_data;
input id 2. class $2. updated_at date9.;
format updated_at date9.;
datalines;
1 X 01jan2020
2 Y 12feb2020
3 Z 01jan2020
4 X 16mar2020
5 Y 23jun2020
6 Z 23jun2020
7 X 31dec2020
;
run;
    
data sas_data;
input id 2. class $2. ;
format updated_at date9.;
updated_at=today();
datalines;
1 Z
3 Z 
5 Z 
7 Z 
8 Y
9 Z
;
run;
```

So, we have changes in id=1, 5 and 7, whereas 3 is unchanged and 8 and 9 are new.
In pure SAS code you can use a data step with update to update and insert in one step, see here:

```
/* Any data row without change has to be eliminated,     */
/* here id=3, otherwise updated_at will be updated there */
proc sql;
  create table changed_data as
  select s.*
  from sas_data s
  left join test_data t
    on s.id eq t.id 
   where s.class ne t.class;
quit;

/* in sas update and insert via data-update-step */
data test_data1;
update test_data changed_data;
by id;
run;
```

As documented, the first sql step is only needed if you don't want to have updated_at to be updated in id=3 because there is no change. But maybe you want to have this updated as well, then you can remove this step.
By the way, precondition here is that the table is sorted by id or there is an index   on id in the table.

But it might be that the SAS data step will not work with the teradata table. Then you could use the following steps in "pure" SQL (starting with the first step above to generate the table changed_data) plus an append step:

```
/* Alternative steps in pure SQL */
/* Step1: SQL-update, no insert  */
proc sql;
update test_data t
set class=(select class from changed_data s where t.id=s.id),
    updated_at=(select updated_at from changed_data s where t.id=s.id)
where id in (select id from changed_data)
; 
quit;
/* Preparation for step2: extract completely new data */
proc sql;
  create table new_data as
  select s.*
  from sas_data s
  where id not in (select id from test_data)
; 
quit;
/* Step2: insert new data via proc-append */
proc append base=test_data 
            data=new_data;
quit;
```

Generally, your performance might be poor with big data sets. Then consider to use a passthrough to the database and use the teradata "upsert", but then you will have to move your sas data into teradata.

Comment: Thank you for this. What I eventually had to do though is push the table into Teradata then use the `merge into` command to update the main table. Turned out to be more efficient.

Comment: That's what I meant with "using passthrough and the teradata functions".